# Select a part of text from the xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

```
<Quote xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <error>TLP3: The product has no marked price;</error>
</Quote>
```

I have an xml stored in a column of a table and I use the following query to extract an xml element :

```
select 
    CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), Response)).value('(/Quote/error)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Exception
```

The result of the expression is :

```
 TL43:The product has no marked price.;
```

I would like to select only the code : `TL43`

And then seperately I would like to select: `The product has no marked price.`

Is there a way I can do it?

XML updated

Comment: could you perhaps give more information on the xml format

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking about a way to do it using TSQL XML capabilities, but basic SQL functionality suffices.

I use a CTE for clarity, but you could mudge it all together without the CTE.

I assume you can convert the final ';' in the source to the '.' in you desired output, if that is actually an requirement.

```
DECLARE @Response VARCHAR(MAX) = '<Quote xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<error>TLP3: The product has no marked price;</error>
</Quote>'

;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(XML,@Response).value('(/Quote/error)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Exception
)
SELECT LEFT(Exception,CHARINDEX(':',Exception)-1) Code
      ,SUBSTRING(Exception,CHARINDEX(':',Exception)+1,LEN(Exception)) Exception
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Response )).value('(/Quote/error)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),0,charindex(':', CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Response )).value('(/Quote/error)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))) as Excepiton
```